# How to animate PNG Sequences and OBJ sequences in Pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

How would I animate a PNG sequence in Pyglet? I want to be able to take, say, a 24-frame animation (each frame is a PNG file) and make it animate in a Pyglet Python program at 24 frames per second. Will the same method apply to OBJ sequences? For example, in Blender I created an OBJ sequence of Sonic jumping and running (each frame of animation is an OBJ file) and I use the Ratcave module to load OBJ Files into my Pyglet application. Would the method of creating an OBJ animation be the same as creating a PNG animation?

It is difficult to find proper animation tutorials for Pyglet. Every one I have searched only tells me how to move, rotate, or scale a single-image sprite across the screen. What I want is to create a complex animation (say, a character walking) and have it play in the Python program. Pyglet is often compared to Pygame, except with better OpenGL 3D capabilities, so I would assume that making a sprite animation would be similar to Pygame. As for Ratcave and OBJ files, it only loads OBJ files, not Collada, FBX, or Egg files, but I have discovered that you can still use OBJ files for animation in After Effects and Unity with certain plugins. When I watched a video on the Ratcave module, I did see an animated dog model in the demonstration, so I am hoping to be able to create a 3D animation with an OBJ sequence.

Comment: Traditional sprite animations are pretty easy. here are some [examples](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31296/2d-animation-example-in-pyglet-python-looping-through-2-images-sprites-every-x) of how you could solve it. And the [documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/image/pyglet.image.Animation.html) on the class used.. and there's even [examples](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/image.html#image-grids) in the docs on how to use it. Anything in particular that's unclear? : )

Comment: Thank you for the examples. 2D animation is easy enough, but what I really want to do is load a sequence of OBJ files and do what is known as mesh key framing—basically, if I have 3 OBJ files, I want to start with the first file, then the second frame be the second file, then the last frame be the third file. Basically, traditional frame-by-frame animation, but with 3D OBJ meshes.

Comment: You're after the same thing I've been looking for a while then. Sorry I can't be of any help. I'll keep an eye here tho to see if you get any results : )

Comment: I found this article that might help us both: https://rdmilligan.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/blender-animation-in-opengl-mark-ii/                                                                             I can't say I fully understand it, though. I already have a good way to import OBJ files (the Ratcave Module) I just need to figure out how to set up the code to flip through each OBJ file like an animation.

Comment: This similar article may help us, too. https://rdmilligan.wordpress.com/2015/11/13/blender-animation-in-opengl/